# IntelliJ - Access is denied when building Artifacts

Tags: java, intellij-idea, permission-denied

I'm trying to export my JavaFX 2 application using IntelliJ 13.1.2 on Windows 8 x64. This is my setup:

[image]

But when I build the artifact I get an error, this is the log:

> Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 7 sec
>
> Information:1 error
>
> Information:0 warnings
>
> Error:Java FX Packager: D:\Dropbox\Development\MultiWork-PC\out\artifacts\MultiWork_PC (Access
>   is denied)

I don't know if it is a bug or more probably some problem with Windows permission. All the files are copied in the Artifact output folder:

[image]

Except the app itself! What I have tried:

1. Running IntelliJ as Administrator
2. Changing folder permission so everyone can write/modify it
3. Changing folder location from D:\, to C:\, Desktop and Documents but still getting the error

NOTE: this doesn't happen if I deploy a jar instead of a JavaFX Application

Comment: Are you always trying to build inside dropbox? Have you tried a normal windows folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried on my C:\ partition, Desktop and Documents folder which are not inside Dropbox. I even tried turning off Dropbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Maven to export my JavaFX app:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>foo.bar.mainclass</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

To clean and build run:

> clean jfx:jar

In your `/target/jfx/app` you will find your executable JavaFX jar file with a `lib` folder containing all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I kind of solved it:

- by ticking the "Build on make" box in the Project Structur Dialog
- starting a Run of my Java App in Intellij Idea

Now the executable jar magically appeared in my build folder.
God knows why.